# TP-Link T1500G-10PS Unable to Access Web Management

Tags: networking, router, dhcp

The topology of my network is the following

Internet -> Modem -> Router (EA9500) -> Switch (T1500G-10PS) -> Laptop

I am getting internet on the laptop; however i am unable to see the IP address of the switch from within my router DHCP table. Doing a tracert on the laptop to google also times out on the switch but continues after that point.

I have personally factory reset the switch twice now. I'm at a loss on how i can access the 192.168.0.1 address that comes default with that.

My Router's settings have an IP of 192.168.1.1 and a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0

The DHCP server settings on the router are:

| setting | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Start IP address | 192.168.1.100 |
| Max Users | 60 |
| IP address range | 192.168.1.100 to 192.168.1.150 |

The above settings seem to make sense to conflict and not allow for the DHCP reservation of the switch but i am unsure on what exactly to update to allow that DHCP reservation to take place? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

It's also worth noting that after a factory restore connecting directly to the switch (at this point its not connected to the router) 192.168.0.1 still does not work for the admin login page.

Comment: Have you tried to manually connect the laptop to the switch, reset the switch and configure your laptop to be in the 192.168.0.0/24 subnet (e.g. 192.168.0.2) and then access the web interface?

Comment: Yes that is what ended up working! Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer through a couple different online forums.

1.) Unplugged connection to router

2.) Factory Reset Switch

3.) Connected laptop directly to the switch as its only connection

4.) Set laptop to the following settings under ethernet

- Ipv4 Address: 192.168.0.10
- Subnet Prefix: 24

  - (note in windows it asks for the prefix NOT the IP)
  - (need to do 24 since the default ip is 192.168.0.1)
- Gateway:192.168.0.1
- DNS: 192.168.0.1

If your switch has a different IP just change the 192.168.0.1 to whatever the default is! Ensure to account for the subnet that the IP falls under.